# What does it mean to refer to some piece of mathematics as "technical"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

We often certain pieces of mathematics described as 'technical'. What does that mean?

To be clear, I am not someone who is literally unsure of the English meaning of the word and looking for a simple explanation.

I am more interested to know if there is any *agreement* among mathematicians about what the word 'technical' actually *connotes*. Specifically, is it a negative connotation? Do you think to yourself 'oh  no I don't want to do *technical* mathematics'? Or do you think 'oh it must have lots of computation' or 'lots of new definitions' or... what?

Comment: I'm not sure that the connotation is actually different than in other fields. Mind you, what's considered technical among mathematicians and what's considered technical to an outsider will, naturally, be vastly different. For example, basic linear algebra, such as Gaussian elimination, wouldn't really be very technical to a mathematician, nor would Euler's formula $e^{i x} = \cos x + i\sin x$. But you'll encounter plenty of mathematicians who aren't familiar with the details of Lie theory.

Comment: But I know even less about what it means in other fields? What is a 'technical' statement in Biology?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based."  This does not mean that it is a bad question---it is, in fact, a very good question.  It just doesn't fit well within the framework of MSE, where questions are supposed to have a single correct answer.  In the case of this question, the word "technical" has no universally agreed upon definition, and is used differently by different mathematicians.

Answer (score 2):

A technical lemma in mathematics refers to something that is needed for a proof but is independent of the proof, and sometimes the subject area, that it is being used for.  Typically it will be highly abstract but will employ mostly elementary machinery, and it will very often serve to move from one thematic portion of the proof to the next in a single statement.

One of the earlier examples of this you may encounter is Young's inequality: let $1/p + 1 /q = 1$ and then
$$ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q} $$
which holds for all non-negative numbers $a,b$.  The proof of this is technical -- there are a few ways to do it, but a common one is by noting that the $\log$ function is concave and this can be re-arranged to take advantage of that.  There is nothing intuitive about this, and at first glance it doesn't look very useful.  However, it is a key element in proving Holder's inequality,
$$\|fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q $$
which turns out to very useful in functional analysis, finite element theory and all kinds of partial differential equation analysis.

A second example would be the lemma concerning re-arrangements of finite sets of numbers in descending order which is used to prove the existence of a locally convex norm (Day's norm) on certain Banach spaces:

Let $s_1 \geq s_2 \geq \cdots \geq 0$ and $t_1 \geq t_2 \geq \cdots \geq 0$ and let $\pi$ be any permutation of the positive integers.  Then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty s_i t_i - \sum_{i=1}^\infty s_i t_{\pi(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( s_i - s_{i-1} \right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^i t_j - \sum_{j=1}^i t_{\pi(j)} \right)$$

Comment: You say that a technical lemma is 1. Needed for a proof, but independent of the proof and 2. Highly abstract, but mostly elementary. This is a bit confusing. Your first example too, is questionable: Many would consider the convexity at the heart of Young's inequality to be the "real truth" behind Holder's inequality. Holder's is more directly applicable in other applications to do with l_p or L^p spaces, but why is there "nothing intuitive" about the proof of Young's using convexity of an elementary function on R? It is arguably much more intuitive than the result about L^p norms it implies.

Comment: @T_M I'm afraid I can't help you in comments; it sounds like you want to have a chat about it.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, a technical lemma is something for which you don't have a really good intuitive motivation, that you don't find to be the heart of the argument but that you need for some reason in your proof. Its proof is typically not illuminating.

If you explain a piece of mathematics to someone over coffee, you would say things like "ok, here is the main idea of the argument: [blabla]. Now, you do need a technical lemma that says [xyz], but let's not bother with why that lemma holds"

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, *technical* also often means (besides what postmortes and Glougloubarbaki say in their answers) something that is swamped with messy details and subtleties. Examples: The two *stability of matter* papers ([1](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1705209) and [2](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1664631)) by Freeman Dyson and Andrew Lenard are very technical. David Preiss' paper [*Geometry of measures in* **R**$^n$: *Distribution, rectifiability, and densities*](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~toro/Courses/07-08/582/preiss.pdf) is very technical.

Comment: I agree that Preiss's paper is very technical, in the sense that I have often heard it described this way. I happen to work in that field and (as you may well know) it is considered a very important paper. I feel that many people in the field would say that paper has some deep and beautiful ideas, but I feel like many other people would think of 'deep and beautiful' to be almost opposite to 'technical'.

Comment: PS personally I think Preiss's paper is indeed both technical and containing deep, beautiful mathematical ideas. In fact this reminds me of what motivated me to ask about the word in the first place: I have the idea to sometimes describe my own work as "technical", but I worry that it has a negative connotation. What I would like is for it to be almost just descriptive and to allow for people to imagine that my work might (aspire to) be like Preiss's.

Comment: @T_M: Especially now, given that many of the ideas in Preiss's paper have generated a lot of important work, perhaps Preiss's paper is not an especially good example of "technical", as I think "technical" tends to also convey a sense of "highly nuanced minutia", which Preiss's paper definitely doesn't have (but which [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540600086) definitely has -- look at its Table of Contents, which can be seen at the amazon.com link I've provided).